# VSTO tools Outlook 2010 differentiate between Appointment and Meeting

Tags: .net, vsto, add-in, outlook-2010

How can I know if a new meeting was clicked or new Appointment was clicked in Outlook 2010? I have a ribbon class in which by looking at `RibbonBase.RibbonId` I can make out if it's `Microsoft.Outlook.Mail` or `Microsoft.Outlook.Appointment` however for Appointment item click and Meeting item click the Ribbon Id holds the value `Microsoft.Outlook.Appointment`. Is there any way to differentiate between Appointments and meetings selection in outlook?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct that Outlook uses the same Ribbon ID (`Microsoft.Outlook.Appointment`) for both Appointments and Meeting items.

To determine which appointment type, [`AppointmentItem.MeetingStatus`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869205.aspx) will be 0 for **Appointment** items, while it will be non-zero for **Meeting** Items.